# how to upgrade the sitecore packages from 9.2 to 9.3 using nuget

Tags: nuget

I am a newbie in sitecore. I have install sitecore Version 9.3 and I have the visual studio solution file with version 9.2(it contains sitecore 9.2 pacakges) i need to upgrade all the dependecy package from 9.2 to 9.3 using nuget or nuget console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to add NuGet feed for Sitecore 9.3

```
Install-Package Sitecore -Version 9.3.0 -Source https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json
```

[image]

Then you need to go `Manage Nuget Package` and search DLL name then click on `update`
[image]

If you want to update multiple projects, then click on "Manage Nuget Packages for solution" and type dll name and check which project you want to update.

[image]

Comment: That's fine swati, but i need to update all package i have 51 projects. so need to upgrade all these.

Comment: Updated answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks swati. Its working.

Comment: how to resolve dependency error for all project..